# From Vector of Tuples to Tuple of Vectors

Tags: arrays, tuples, julia

In Julia, many things are represented as Arrays of small Tuples, such as `Point`s. But sometimes you'd like the elements separate, such as extracting x and y coordinates for plotting - e.g. to have a tuple of Arrays. You can partly use `zip`:

```
pts = [(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,2)]
a,b = collect(zip(pts...))
```

This leads to a tuple of tuples though, although you can

```
av = [a...]
bv = [b...]
```

Is there a more convenient way of doing this operation?

Comment: what's wrong with bare comprehensions? `av = [i[1] for i in pts]`

Comment: Nothing as such, except this requires N passes of the array and doesn't look so pretty :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Courtesy of Tim Holy, there is the MappedArray package. With it, the following could be easy on the eyes and processor:

```
julia> using MappedArrays

julia> struct Point
       x::Float64
       y::Float64
       end

julia> pvec = [Point(rand(),rand()) for i=1:10];

julia> b = mappedarray(e->e.x,pvec);

julia> b[3]
0.9524214421389912

julia> b
10-element MappedArrays.ReadonlyMappedArray{Float64,1,Array{Point,1},##3#4}:
 0.383683
 0.474853
 0.952421
 0.388564
 0.268427
 0.301026
 0.117767
 0.712266
 0.629364
 0.227822
```

As usual, performance should be explicitly measured, but should be OK if things get inlined properly.

UPDATE

For a Vector of Tuples it would be `mappedarray(e->first(e),tvec)` and variations. For example:

```
julia> tvec = [(rand(),rand()) for i=1:10000];

julia> c = mappedarray(x->first(x),tvec);

julia> c[5]
0.8626336507168362
```

And the kicker is, turns out `sum(c)` is fast:

```
julia> @btime sum(first.(tvec))
  21.643 μs (25 allocations: 79.23 KiB)
5000.93749585252

julia> @btime sum(c)
  9.850 μs (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
5000.937495852521

julia> @btime sum(first(x) for x in tvec)
  10.560 μs (2 allocations: 32 bytes)
5000.937495852521
```

Comment: Love it! :heart_eyes:

Comment: aha, a lazy and consice way better than comprehension.